# Find number of position n each deparment

Tags: oracle, find, max

Tables CRIMES, SUSPECTS

How many women and how many men have committed crimes in the car theft.

table crimes:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGycX.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iumlW.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iiT6.png) so on...

table Suspects:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icMRO.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ITF5.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXKWU.png) so on...

I made some work, but my soulition did not accepted by SQL

> select name, sex,  crime_type,  count(case when sex='Male' then 1 end)
> as male_cnt, count(case when sex='Female' then 1 end) as female_cnt
> from suspects NATURAL JOIN crimes where crime_type='Car Theft' group
> by name, sex;

Blockquote

Comment: Hello and welcome to the SO. Aikul. could you please update the question with the test data in some fomat other that links or images? Thanks

Comment: At first glance, you're missing CRIME_TYPE in the GROUP BY clause: `GROUP BY name, sex, crime_type;`

Comment: How is the question title related to the body of the question?

Answer (score 0):

> How many women and how many men have committed crimes in the car theft.

The question only asks for the gender and the count so you do not need to include the name or the crime type in the output.

If you want a single row then you want to aggregate over the entire result-set and can use your conditional aggregation for each gender:

```sql
select count(case when s.sex='Male' then 1 end) as male_cnt,
       count(case when s.sex='Female' then 1 end) as female_cnt
from   suspects s
       INNER JOIN crimes c
       ON (s.suspect_id = c.suspect_id)
where  c.crime_type='Car Theft';
```

or, if you want one row-per-gender then:

```sql
select s.sex,
       count(*) as cnt
from   suspects s
       INNER JOIN crimes c
       ON (s.suspect_id = c.suspect_id)
where  c.crime_type='Car Theft'
GROUP BY s.sex;
```